# C - Why variables created in a loop have the same memory address?

Tags: c, memory, memory-address

Just a simple example of my problem:

```
while(condition){
    int number = 0;
    printf("%p", &number);
}
```

That variable will always be in the same memory address. Why?

And what's the real difference between declaring it inside or outside the loop then?

Would I need to `malloc` the variable every iteration to get different addresses?

Comment: Why should it have a different address?  If that address is available, why not use/reuse it?

Comment: Why do you care if the memory address is the same?

Comment: I don't know, it's not a complaint though... it's a curiosity

Comment: Are you trying to assign the address of that variable to some external variable?  If so that won't work because the lifetime of `number` ends at the end of the loop.

Comment: well it's not the case but imagine I'm saving the number in a collection. All my collection would be pointing to the same place, right?

Comment: `int` is a value type, not a pointer type.  When you assign it, you're assigning the *value,* not the address.

Answer (score 10):

> That variable will always be in the same memory address. Why?

It's not required to, but your code is so simple that it probably will be across all platforms. Specifically, because it's stored on the stack, it's always in the same place relative to your stack pointer. Keep in mind you're not allocating memory here (no `new` or `malloc`), you're just naming existing (stack-relative) memory.

> And what's the real difference between declaring it inside or outside the loop then?

In this case, scope. The variable doesn't exist outside the braces where it lives in. Also outside of the braces, another variable can take its place if it fits in memory and the compiler chooses to do this.

> Would I need to malloc the variable every iteration to get different addresses?

Yes, but I have yet to see a good use of `malloc` to allocate space for an `int` that a simple stack variable or a standard collection wouldn't do better.

Comment: Might be a dumb question but when is `malloc` really necessary? What if I would be adding that number to a collection? Should I not need to ensure every number would be in a different place?

Comment: No, the collection already has an array waiting for new elements, you're simply copying the value of your integer to one of the cells in the array waiting for data.

Comment: @walkman You need `malloc` if you need to dynamically allocate memory ;-) On a more serious note: if you need the allocated memory to survive beyond the current scope, e.g. to return a pointer to it from a function. That said, you need to clearly document ownership of memory allocated with `malloc`, in order to know which part of the code is responsible for invoking `free` on it when it is no longer needed.

Comment: @walkman Of course, it is possible to write entire applications in C without dynamic memory allocation - in fact that is quite common in realtime systems. All available memory is pre-allocated in these scenarios, in order to have more predictable runtime characteristics. So, in a way, you don't *need* `malloc` at all.

Comment: @Hulk can I deviate the question to a much more specific case then?

Comment: It is probably better to ask a new question in that case.

Answer (score 5):

> *That variable will always be in the same memory address. Why?*

The compiler decides where the variable should be, given the operating system constraints, it's much more efficient to maintain the variable at the same address than having it relocated at every iteration, but this could, theoretically, happen.

You can't rely on it being in the same address every time.

> *And what's the real difference between declaring it inside or outside the loop then?*

The difference is lifetime of the variable, if declared within the loop it will only exist inside the loop, you can't access it after the loop ends.

When execution of the block ends the lifetime of the object ends and it can no longer be accessed.

> *Would I need to malloc the variable every iteration to get different addresses?*

`malloc` is an expensive operation, it does not make much sense to malloc the variable at every iteration, that said, again, the compiler decides where the memory for it is allocated, it may very well be at the same address or not.

Once again you can't rely on the variable location in the previous iteration to assert where it will be on the next one.

There is a difference in the the variables are stored, allocated variables will be on the heap, as opposed to the stack like in the previous case.

Comment: @FiddlingBits, lol, sorry about that, it's the initials of operating system in my language.

Comment: système opérateur

Comment: @FiddlingBits, sistema operativo

Comment: @anastaciu: Re “you can't access it outside”: That should say “after,” not “outside” the loop. You can access an object outside of the block it is defined in, as when it is passed by address to a subroutine. It is when execution of the block ends that the lifetime of the object ends and it should no longer be accessed. Issues of **scope** are about **identifiers** and **where** they may be accessed. Issues of **lifetime** are about **objects** and **when** they may be accessed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, good catch, corrected it. I used a part of your comment in the correction, forgive for plagiarising you.

Answer (score 3):

It is being put into the same memory address to save memory.

The only real difference between declaring it within and without the loop is that the variable will no longer be within scope outside the loop if it was declared within the loop.

You would have to use `malloc` to get a different address each time. Also, you would have to leave the `free`s until after all the `malloc`s to get this guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

> That variable will always be in the same memory address. Why?

The *object* that `number` designates has `auto` storage duration and only exists for the lifetime of the loop body, so *logically* speaking a new instance is created and destroyed on each loop iteration.

*Practically* speaking, it's easier to just re-use the same memory location for each loop iteration, which is what most (if not all) C compilers do.  It's just not guaranteed to retain its last value from one iteration to the next (especially if you initialize it each iteration).

> And what's the real difference between declaring it inside or outside the loop then?

The *lifetime* of the object (the period of program execution where storage is guaranteed to be reserved for it) changes from the body of the loop to the body of the function.  The *scope* of the identifier (the region of program text where the identifier is visible) changes from the body of the loop to the body of the entire function.

Again, *practically* speaking, most compilers will allocate stack space for `auto` objects that are in blocks at function entry - for example, given the code

```
void foo( void )
{
  int bar;
  while ( bar = 0; bar < 10; bar++ )
  {
    int bletch = 2 * bar;
    ...
  }
}
```

most compilers will generate instructions to reserve stack space for both `bar` *and* `bletch` at function entry, rather than waiting until loop entry to reserve space for `bletch`.  It's just easier to set the stack pointer *once* and get it over with.  Storage is *guaranteed* to be reserved for `bletch` over the lifetime of the loop body, but there's nothing in the language definition that says you can't reserve it before then.

However, if you have a situation like this:

```
void foo( void )
{
  int bar;
  while ( bar = 0; bar < 10; bar++ )
  {
    if ( bar % 2 == 0 ) // bar is even
    {
      int bletch = 2 * bar;
      ...
    }
    else
    {
      int blurga = 3 * bar + 1;
      ...
    }
  }
```

`bletch` and `blurga` cannot exist at the same time, so the compiler *may* only allocate space for one additional `int` object, and that same space will be used for either `bletch` or `blurga` depending on the value of `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

There are compilers that, despite you declaring the variable in the inner loop, just allocate them at the entry to the function block.

Modern compilers tend to allocate all memory for local variables in a single shot at function entry, so that only represents a single stack pointer move, against several push pop instructions to get the same result.

Despite of that, there's another issue you have not considered.  The variable in the inner loop is not visible outside the loop, and the memory used by it can be used for a different variable outside.  You know that the memory address is always the same... but you don't know when you are  out of scope if any of the other variables you use for a different thing are given the same address by the compiler (that's perfectly legal, as your variable is automatic, and so, it ceases to exist as soon as you get out of the block (the pair of curly brackets you put around the loop)